# I want to extend the mobile search on click to the desktop

Tags: magento2.4, search, mobile, customize

I want to extend the onclick search bar like in mobile view to the desktop view also, how can i do this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the older version approach over here - you need to create a new mobile site or if you wanted to do it with an existing site - then you need to Structure level changes in Magento.

As Magento is using bootstrap responsive framework for mobile devices so you wanted to eliminate it and need to use desktop CSS js on mobile as well.